# How to change codeception phpbrowser/mink timeout

Tags: php, mink, codeception

I'm trying to create test with codeception that will check's the page is properly working in case of high load.

Unfortunately if the page is in very very high load and the tests starts I got such error:

```
[..] 
[Codeception\Exception\ModuleConfig]
Codeception\Util\Mink module is not configured!
Provided URL can't be accessed by this driver.[curl] 28: Operation timed out after 30031
milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received [url] http://xxxx.xxx/app_db2.php
[..]
```

Is there any possibility to set the Mink timeout to some higher value ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set curl options via your test suit configuration just like in [example](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser) in Codeception docs.

In your case you need CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, see [curl_setopt reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
modules: 
    enabled: [PhpBrowser]  
      config:
        PhpBrowser:
          url: 'http://localhost' 
          curl:
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: 50000 # timeout in seconds
```

Comment: CURLOPT_TIMEOUT unit is seconds. For ms use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS

Comment: my Codeception completely ignores this setting and still times out after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the following post: [Codeception ignores CURLOPT_TIMEOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220000/codeception-ignores-curlopt-timeout/35953866#35953866)

There is a codeception bug that prevents this value from being set.  With more recent versions of codeception, >=2.0.15, you can pass CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS to accomplish what you are trying to do.