# Codeception ignores CURLOPT_TIMEOUT

Tags: curl, codeception, acceptance-testing

This is the content of the acceptance.suite.yml

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
    - PhpBrowser:
        url: http://reoc.lo/
        curl:
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: 50000 # timeout in seconds
    - \Helper\Acceptance
```

I did this following this question: [How to change codeception phpbrowser/mink timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757141/how-to-change-codeception-phpbrowser-mink-timeout)
but it doesn't work for me as it skips this setting and it's timing out on 30 seconds which is the default.

Are there any other settings to override default CURLOPT_TIMEOUT?

Comment: So 50,000 seconds is an awfully long time, is that what you had intended? How do you know it's not working? I presume that it is timing out sooner than expected.

Comment: I wasn't clear! It skips this setting and it's timing out on 30 seconds which is the default.

Comment: I can also confirm this behavior. It doesn't matter if its 5 or 50000 it doesn't read the setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, now to answer your question.  Codeception introduced a bug by fixing another bug.  First bug https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1984 was fixed whcih lowered the default timeout.  Then they realised that no one could set a timeout so they released this fix:  https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/pull/2065

Long story short, use >=2.0.15 and set the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS option